# Query PostGIS radius giving me odd results

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm new to PostGIS and I'm trying to create a radius query. I have a table with a `geometry` field (position) and also have the latitude and longitude values on separate fields.

I'm trying to find points on a 10 km radius from lat: 40.753777, lon: -73.981568.

with:

```
SELECT postcode, lat, lon, st_asgeojson(position) geojson, ST_Distance(ST_MakePoint(lat, lon), ST_MakePoint(40.753777, -73.981568)) distance FROM addresses WHERE ST_DWithin(ST_MakePoint(lat, lon), ST_MakePoint(40.753777, -73.981568), 10000) order by id limit 10;
```

The results give me very far a way points. The same query with earth distance using the lat and lon directly give me much closer results.

```
SELECT postcode, lat, lon, st_asgeojson(position) geojson FROM addresses WHERE earth_box(ll_to_earth(40.753777, -73.981568), 10000) @> ll_to_earth(addresses.lat, addresses.lon) order by id limit 10;
```

But I really don't know if this is right either, what's wrong with the PostGIS query?

Comment: Longitude and latitude have nothing to do with meters, so I don't think that is surprising. If the data points are too distributed to be reasonably transformed to an appropriate projection, you could use `geography`.

Comment: On a side note, points must be created using long first, then lat

Comment: Hi @LaurenzAlbe thanks for your reply, I thought for distances could be calculated on geometry fields, to get distances from a point Geography must be used? Do you know which SRID do I use to find by meters?

Comment: @JGH yes, my geo json created out of lat 42.035149 and lon -78.8768906 resulted in {"type":"Point","coordinates":[-78.8768906,42.035149]}

Answer (score 1):

A few notes:

1. I think you swapped the lat and lon when you made a point, your line says ST_MakePoint(40.753777, -73.981568), but the definition is:

> ```
> geometry ST_MakePoint(double precision x, double precision y);
> Note: x is longitude and y is latitude
> ```

So it should have been ST_MakePoint(-73.981568, 40.753777) instead.

2. As a simple solution you can use ST_Distance_Spheroid function ( http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Distance_Spheroid.html ):

> ```
> SELECT
>     postcode, lat, lon, st_asgeojson(position) AS geojson,
>     ST_Distance_Spheroid(
>         position,
>         ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-73.981568 40.753777)',
>         4326), 'SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]'
>     ) as distance
> FROM addresses 
> WHERE distance < 10000 LIMIT 10;
> ```

3. For a more precise distances, add a new column of type geography from you existing column `position` of type geometry:

> ```
> ALTER TABLE addresses ADD COLUMN position_geog geography(Point,4326);
> UPDATE addresses SET position_geog = position::geography;
> CREATE INDEX ON addresses USING gist(position_geog);
> -- and now you can use ST_DWITHIN with meters...
> ```